# How to fix persistant cracks on this section of the wall and why do they show up even after repainting?

Tags: walls, painting, crack

There is a section of the wall in the bedroom that even though been repainted several times by actual painters, within weeks the cracks would resurface again. im trying to figure out if there is an easy temporary fix since im not painting the room again, and what should i take into consideration next time i decide to repaint the room? This is concrete or whatever, not drywall. Here is what some of the cracks look like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can tell the crack has been patched, because the texture is different than the rest of the wall. You say, "this is concrete...not drywall."  If so, you're probably looking at a "cold joint" or there's expansion or contraction occurring in the second pic. Something different is causing the "patch" appearance in the first pic. To fix this you'd need to isolate the area (so the wall can move without damaging the coating/paint) around the cracked area and then re-patch, texture and paint.

Comment: Yes the crack was there before it was patched. This is just one example, the while section of the wall, it's paint is barely holding onto the wall, and a line of cracks runs straight up. The first pic though happened after i pulling out blu-tack. How do I isolate, repatch? Would that require I tear down old paint?

Comment: Yes, I think the only way to solve the issue is to start with the prep of the wall. All buildings move, we just try to limit the movement and have them move together, (as opposed to differential settlement.) To keep painting over a crack without fixing the original crack is a lot like what @brhans says about scotch tape...

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st picture shows an issue where you have a layer of paint which is not well adhered to the surface underneath (and probably more layers painted on top of that).
This is like putting a piece of scotch-tape onto a dusty surface and expecting it to stick.
More and more layers of paint will never fix this.
You'd need to strip/scrape/peel all of the old paint off until you get back down to something solid and start the paint journey over again from scratch.

While doing this you'll probably also find what's under that crack in the 2nd picture - there's likely still movement on each side of the crack, but it might be possible to manage this once you know what's under there...

Comment: I didn't paint this room a professional did. What did he do wrong? Do I have to redo it, can I just wait for a couple of years if it's that big if a problem?

Comment: Whoever last painted the room probably assumed that the previous paint job was done properly - in which case simply covering the old with the new is the standard procedure. If this is the wall's 1st coat of paint, then somebody did something wrong - difficult to say exactly what - maybe wrong kind of paint, maybe needed a primer (or better primer).